# linux command line to zip files based on mysql resultset

Tags: mysql, linux, zip

i have a table, where some filenames are stored.

i would like to find all the files having that name under a specific folder and zip all of them.

on disk the structure is similar to this:

/folder/sub1/file1

/folder/sub1/file2

/folder/sub2/file1 <- same name as under sub1

/folder/sub2/file2

so i am looking for something similar to:

```
mysql -e "select file from table" | find /folder -type f -name <the value of file from mysql result set> | zip <all files found by all find commands>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of additions to your command:

Firstly, you want to use `mysql` in *batch* mode, so you do this:

```
mysql -Be "select file from table"
```

It gives you a single column table with no borders, so you get rid of the headers by piping it to `tail` starting at the second line:

```
tail -n +2
```

Then you pipe that to `xargs`, but before you do, hack it a bit with `concat` (you'll see why in a sec):

```
mysql -Be "select concat(' -o -name ', file) from table"
```

NOW you pipe it to `xargs`:

```
xargs find /folder -false
```

This does a "false" test (i.e. a no-op), but it appends a whole pile of things like `-o -name somename.file`, each of which performs a boolean `or` (with `false` originally, later with all other file names) and ultimately returns the list of files that match.

...which you finally pipe to `zip`, with another xargs:

```
xargs zip files.zip
```

Again, this puts the file names as arguments to `zip`.

Here's the total line:

```
mysql -Be "select concat(' -o -name ', file) from table" | tail -n +2 | xargs find /folder -false | xargs zip files.zip
```

Bear in mind that this assumes you have no spaces in your filenames. If you do, that'll add a bit of complexity: You can work around that by using `-print0` and `-0` in `find` and `xargs` respectively, although `zip` will have a harder time with that so you'd need to add another intermediate stage (or use `zip -r`).

Comment: i use in mysql command the following options -N -r -s, which remove the header and all the formatting.

but your solution is brilliant, works excellent :) thanks.

Comment: again ... brilliant, that thing with find -false :)